# Can “manche” induce singular? (“Winterreise” example)

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, poetry, indefinite-pronoun

In Müller-Schubert’s *Winterreise* the sixth lied begins with

> Manche Trän’ aus meinen Augen
>   ist gefallen in den Schnee: (…)

Why is *Manche Trän(e[n])* in singular? Is this rather a “I have to accept it like this because it’s poetry” and in that case I’d like to know the meaning or effect of using the singular, or, I need to think of it as meaning *sind gefallen* instead (which I doubt).

Or, is *Manche* and not *manche*?  That is, it’s a noun (which I also doubt, since I cannot find it as a noun in the dictionaries).

Comment: As you can see for example on [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/manch#Bedeutung1), **manch-** can be used in singular.

Comment: "Manche Träne" is regular German, no artistic license needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The indefinite pronoun *manch* can be used in singular as well as in plural. This is reflected in the English translation with *many*:

- singular: **Many a tear** from my eyes **has** fallen into the snow.
- plural: **Many tears** from my eyes **have** fallen into the snow.

*Manch* has distinct singular and plural inflections, but the feminine singular inflection happens to be the same as the plural inflection in all three genders, which might be a cause for confusion at first:

**A) SINGULAR inflections of manch (e.g. nominative and accusative case):**

> **manche** Träne (fem.); **mancher** Mensch (masc.); **manches** Haus (neut.)

**B) PLURAL inflection (e.g. nominative and accusative case):**

> **manche** Tränen (fem.); **manche** Menschen (masc.); **manche** Häuser (neut.)

---

More on the inflection of 'manch' [here in canoo.](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-manch3.html?lang=en)

Comment: Of course all plurals would be like feminine singular. They all have *die*. Gender distinctions are lost in plurals (hence the tendency for PC language to use unclear plural forms). If one grammatical gender’s plural is like feminine singular, they will all be. It’s more of a rule than an exception (though it still has exceptions: dative plural being the most prominent).

Comment: @Jan This is a weird way of thinking of it. It will also mostly confuse people. Just because the article is *die*, it doesn't suddenly make a noun feminine singular. *Die Männer* is still masculine nominative plural and you should really not be saying *die Männer* is feminine, but *der Mann* is masculine.

Answer (score 2):

It's most certainly not a noun. Duden (German dictionary, like Webster) doesn't know of it and neither do I (rather well-educated native speaker).

I am very sure that *Manche trän'* means manche Träne which does make sense as in some or numerous tears. A little like focusing on each individual tear rhetorically/symbolically, giving them more gravitas. Using this phrase in normal conversation would sound rather puffy though, at least in my opinion, roughly comparable to speaking like a protagonist out of a shakespearean play.

Duden also mentions that manch(e[r]) means an individual person or thing, that sums up with more of its kind to a quantity that matters, but the exact count is not given OR (like in this case) some, but not all persons or things among others, but to an extent that it matters  (rough translation of [Duden's](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/manch) definition)

Interestingly enough, I might not have noticed that myself. It would be great to hear from someone who knows a little more about the grammatical aspect of it.